# Magento 2 : How to display the category image in the topmenu

Tags: magento2, category, menu, category-tree, topmenu

How to display the category image in the topmenu?

I need to edit/overwrite the block file, but I can't get the code to actually extract the image.

Comment: you have to override Topmenu.php file.

Comment: Yes, that I know, it is the code to overwrite it with that I need

Comment: How about your current issue? There is an update from my answer, please check again.

Answer (score 13):

Look at

**vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu">
        <plugin name="catalogTopmenu" type="Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu" />
</type>
```

As we can see, Magento uses [Plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) - `Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu` to override some methods of `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu` class. We should see more **vendor/magento/module-catalog/Plugin/Block/Topmenu.php**.

We can disable the default plugin in your module and re-build your own Plugin which follow the logic of `Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu` class.

**Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml**

```
 <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu">
        <plugin name="catalogTopmenu" disabled="true" />
        <plugin name="catalogTopmenuImage" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Topmenu" />
 </type>
```

From my understanding, we should to rebuild some methods:

**vendor/magento/module-catalog/Plugin/Block/Topmenu.php**

```
...

/**
 * Convert category to array
 *
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $currentCategory
 * @return array
 */
private function getCategoryAsArray($category, $currentCategory)
{
    return [
        'name' => $category->getName(),
        'id' => 'category-node-' . $category->getId(),
        'url' => $this->catalogCategory->getCategoryUrl($category),
        'has_active' => in_array((string)$category->getId(), explode('/', $currentCategory->getPath()), true),
        'is_active' => $category->getId() == $currentCategory->getId(),
        'image_url' => $category->getImageUrl(), // Get image URL
    ];
}

/**
 * Get Category Tree
 *
 * @param int $storeId
 * @param int $rootId
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
protected function getCategoryTree($storeId, $rootId)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection $collection */
    $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    $collection->setStoreId($storeId);
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('image'); // Select image
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('path', ['like' => '1/' . $rootId . '/%']); //load only from store root
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1);
    $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
    $collection->addUrlRewriteToResult();
    $collection->addOrder('level', Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
    $collection->addOrder('position', Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
    $collection->addOrder('parent_id', Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
    $collection->addOrder('entity_id', Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);

    return $collection;
}

...
```

You can then use `$child->getDataByKey('image_url')` in `Topmenu::_getHtml()` (via an extending module, as explained [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/134106/44037)). For example, the below will replace the category name with the image (if there is one):

```
protected function _getHtml(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree,
    $childrenWrapClass,
    $limit,
    $colBrakes = []
) {
    $html = '';

    $children = $menuTree->getChildren();
    $parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
    $childLevel = $parentLevel === null ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

    $counter = 1;
    $itemPosition = 1;
    $childrenCount = $children->count();

    $parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
    $itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $child->setLevel($childLevel);
        $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
        $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
        $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

        $outermostClassCode = '';
        $outermostClass = $menuTree->getOutermostClass();

        if ($childLevel == 0 && $outermostClass) {
            $outermostClassCode = ' class="' . $outermostClass . '" ';
            $child->setClass($outermostClass);
        }

        if (count($colBrakes) && $colBrakes[$counter]['colbrake']) {
            $html .= '</ul></li><li class="column"><ul>';
        }

        $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
        $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>';

        // Use category image instead of name if available
        $html .= $child->getDataByKey('image_url') ? '<img src="' . $child->getDataByKey('image_url') . '">' : $this->escapeHtml($child->getName());

        $html .= '</span></a>' . $this->_addSubMenu(
            $child,
            $childLevel,
            $childrenWrapClass,
            $limit
        ) . '</li>';
        $itemPosition++;
        $counter++;
    }

    if (count($colBrakes) && $limit) {
        $html = '<li class="column"><ul>' . $html . '</ul></li>';
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: I saw that already, but what is the code to get the image?

Comment: We can disable the default plugin in your module and re-build your own Plugin which follows the logic of `Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu` class.

Comment: I do not have any folder `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Plugin/Block`. In  `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Plugin` , I just got `Model`

Comment: I used Magento version 2.1: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Plugin/Block/Topmenu.php`. Please check again.

Comment: I was still in 2.0.7, doing the upgrade now

Comment: Hi @Khoa TruongDinh,  how to get category images along with the links, ie) i need to category image for 1st category, for 2nd category, need to get default magento links, 3rd category need to get both images and links, could you please suggest on this?

Comment: A solution with the same principle but cleaner can be found here: http://catgento.com/2017/03/20/magento-2-display-category-image-in-navigation-menu . Actually, it's not necessary to rewrite all the code, because the _getHtml function calls itself again and again.

Comment: Hi @KhoaTruongDinh, i have tried this but the image also appears on category page. i only want image with category name as link in navigation menu for mobile view only. Can u pls help me in this.

Comment: getCategoryAsArray method is private how can we modify it?