# How to override blocks in v2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, theme

I'm trying to override the Topmenu block in Magento 2.1 but can't find any guide to do so. Everything I've found on here and elsewhere either seems to apply only to version 2.0 which appears to use a different folder structure or only has partial code examples which expects me to already know their proper context (which I don't).

My current folder structure for a custom theme is `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme_name`. Within this I have the registration, theme, and composer files as well as folders for the various modules, e.g. `Magento_Theme` and `Magento_Search`.

From what I understand I need to start with an `etc/di.xml` file like below, edited from [here](http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/magento-2-overriding-block-model-controller-magento2/):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
</config>
```

I also understand that the next step is to add a `Block/Html/Topmenu.php` file like the below (again edited from the above source):

```
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Html;

class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{

  protected function _addSubMenu($child, $childLevel, $childrenWrapClass, $limit)
  {

  }

}
```

However, it's not clear to me what I should use for `[Namespace]` and `[Module]`, or where to place these files. I've tried using the vendor and theme name, and placing the `etc` and `Block` folders in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme_name`, as well as placing them in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme_name/Magento_Theme`, amending the namespaces to `Vendor\theme_name\Magento_Theme\Block\Html`, but neither have any effect.

If anyone could help explain exactly what I need to do to override the Topmenu block (and by inference any other block) in version 2.1 I would be much appreciated.

**Addendum**

I've attempted [Khoa TruongDinh](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/134106/44037)'s answer but it has had no affect. I've used the following files:

`app/code/Vendor/MagentoTheme/Block/Html/Topmenu.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\MagentoTheme\Block\Html;

class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{

  protected function _addSubMenu($child, $childLevel, $childrenWrapClass, $limit)
  {

    $html = '';

    if (!$child->hasChildren())
    {
      return $html;
    }

    $colStops = null;

    if ($childLevel == 0 && $limit)
    {
      $colStops = $this->_columnBrake($child->getChildren(), $limit);
    }

    // Added "test" class to test
    $html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . ' test submenu">';
    $html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass, $limit, $colStops);
    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;

  }

}
```

`app/code/Vendor/MagentoTheme/composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "vendor/magento-theme",
    "description": "",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "100.0.1",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Vendor\\MagentoTheme\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

`app/code/Vendor/MagentoTheme/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Vendor\MagentoTheme\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
</config>
```

`app/code/Vendor/MagentoTheme/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_MagentoTheme" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

`app/code/Vendor/MagentoTheme/registration.php`

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
  \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
  'Vendor_MagentoTheme',
  __DIR__
);
```

I've then removed the contents of `pub/static/frontend`, `var/generation`, and `var/view_preprocessed`, and flushed the Magento cache. The submenu doesn't have the intended "test" class added:

```
<ul class="level0 submenu ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="menu" aria-expanded="false" style="display: none; top: 52.6719px; left: 487.5px;" aria-hidden="true">...</ul>
```

Comment: You tried to create multi sub categories?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. At the moment I'm just trying to add a "test" class to the submenu `ul` to confirm that I've successfully overriden the Topmenu class.

Comment: How you can do this? My guide can help you?

Comment: I followed your instructions as best I understood but it didn't work. My custom Topmenu module is ignored and the default behaviour is being used.

Comment: At the weekend,  I will check again and give you my solution.

Comment: Much appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Override block:**

Create your own module under `app/code` folder.
We can use `preference` to override the class in Magento 2.

*app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
</config>
```

*app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Html/Topmenu.php*

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Html;

class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{

    protected function _addSubMenu($child, $childLevel, $childrenWrapClass, $limit)
    {

    }

}
```

**Temporary solution:**
Currently, seem that above steps cannot override the the block completely. We need to create new custom theme. And then, create the `default.xml` file:

*app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="default_head_blocks"/>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Html\Topmenu" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml"/>
</page>
```

It's may be a Magento bug: [Are we forced to rewrite a template in Magento2 when rewritting a block?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115988/are-we-forced-to-rewrite-a-template-in-magento2-when-rewritting-a-block)

**[EDIT]**

1) We can set the template:

*app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Html/Topmenu.php*

```
public function setTemplate($template)
{
    return parent::setTemplate('Vendor_Module::custom-menu.phtml');
}
```

2) Set template via Xml:

For example:

*app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout::cart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Remember to create `registration.php` and `module.xml`.

We create the new module because we're overriding the class of Magento. **When we want to override any class, we have to create new module**.

The custom theme under `app/design/frontend` contains:
*--layout

--templates

--js

--html templates (Knockout templates)

--less, css

--etc...*

Read more [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/build/module-file-structure.html) and [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html).

**Autoloading standard and naming convention:**

For `[Namespace]` and `[Module]`, we should read more here:

http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/
http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/
http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_autoloader_and_class_generation

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't able to get this to work. I've edited my attempt into my question so you can see where I inevitably went wrong.

Comment: What's the template?

Comment: I updated my answer. Seem that there is a Magento bug. We need to create new custom theme. And then, create the layout to set the class again.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you very much. A day wasted on a bug...

Comment: i have to override block file in custom_account_create.xml located in my custom theme.xml file is in Magento_Customer folder.which default.xml i have to change magento_theme or magento_customer??i am unable to override block.i am using Magento2.1 is it better to move Magento 2.1.3??

Comment: Shouldn't we execute `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` after this??

Answer (score 3):

**For override catalog product ListProduct block.**

**1)** Create **di.xml** file in Folder `Vendor/Module/etc`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Rewrite\Catalog\Product" />
</config>
```

**2)** Create **ListProduct.php** Block file in Folder `Vendor/Module/Block/Rewrite/Product`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Rewrite\Product;

class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    public function _getProductCollection()
    {
        // Do your code here
    }
}
```

**For override catalog product model.**

**1)** Add preference in di.xml before

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Rewrite\Catalog\Product" />
</config>
```

**2)** Create **Product.php** Model file in Folder `Vendor/Module/Model/Rewrite/Catalog`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Rewrite\Catalog;

class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
{
    public function isSalable()
    {
        // Do your code here

        return parent::isSalable();
    }

}
```

**For Overriding Controller**

**1)** Add preference in **di.xml**

**2)** Create **View.php** Controller file at `Vendor/Module/Controller/Rewrite/Product`

```
class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View
{
    public function execute()
    {
        // Do your stuff here
        return parent::execute();
    }
}
```

You can override other block,model and controllers using this same approach.

Comment: Looks like override of class \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct does not work (in Magento 2.2 Maybe?), refer link - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13152

Answer (score 0):

To override the class you have to create a module where you can add the `etc/di.xml` and `Block/Html/Topmenu.php` file (above code posted by you)

where **Namespace** is your vendor name and **Module** is your module name. For ex: Magento is Namespace and Theme is Module name.

For more info on how to create a module, http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/build/module-file-structure.html#module-file-structure

Answer (score 0):

Because of this bug: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3724 you cannot just preference block classes.

1) (Preferable) What works instead is to use a **Plugin** for that class and change what you need to. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

2) Or if you really want to do the preference way then you need to also copy the template from core to your module/theme and update with xml so that uses that template instead, then it will magically start working..