# Is it okay to change the vendor files?

Tags: magento-2.1, module, custom-options, customer-account, ultimo

I am using magento 2.1 with the ultimo theme. I was customizing the login page which was not avaialable as a module in the theme.

So I go to vendor and changed the login page setting like text and placement of new register and old customer login place.

I want to ask is it okay to change these files . I know after the changes I have to compile so that these changes make it to the pub.

But in the vendor what should be done for the best practice.

**P.S** the path is `/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/newcustomer.phtml`

Comment: changing any file in vendor is not the right way, its total wrong way... extend your module under your ultimo theme..

Comment: @ManojDeswal how ? i have already extended the ultimo theme.

Comment: extend customer module under ultimo theme... let me see the your theme directory then I ll tell you where to place the files

Comment: sure it will be a great help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not best practice. If you run any updates these changes will get overwritten. Any patches that are applied may fail if the files are different from originals as well.

You can, however, do this from within your theme. From your ultimo theme's root directory create new folders for that module **Magento_Customer/templates**.

Then copy the vendor file to your new folder:

> **Magento_Customer/templates/newcustomer.phtml**

Then make modifications to your new file from there.

Comment: actually there is nothing like Magento_Customer. Also there is xml file in view which i also want to change i want to change the settings of the block thats why

Comment: Yeah add the folders in there .

Comment: The xml file will go within Magento_Customer/layout/ you can make changes to xml from there.

Comment: thats what i am saying that there is not any folder like magento_customer in ultimo . Do i have to make one? and which files should i copy. It will automatically pick up the files which i have changed from this new directory and old files from vendor?

Comment: Yeah so create the new directories Magento_Customer , and templates within that. These files will now be used instead of vendor files.

Comment: all the files or only the files which i want to change ?

Comment: Just the files you want to change

Comment: Looks good. thank you for your help harri!

Comment: If i want to change the block the procedure is same ?

Comment: What is the file you want to change?

Comment: Login.php i want to change the title

Comment: This is more for a module where you can override the block see: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134093/how-to-override-blocks-in-v2-1/134106 Within theme however you can create customer_account_login.xml with some code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66321/discussion-between-harri-and-tech-geek).

Comment: i have understand but what how would i know the action methods that which method i should change. Like in this case we are changing the title method.

Comment: I'm not sure i can give a great answer to this i think this would make a decent question on its own I will try look for something regarding this.

Comment: sure it will be a great help

Answer (score 5):

To make changes in your **customer module** , copy file from vendor at path you changing right now

```
/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/newcustomer.phtml
```

And place at following location in your theme, if folders are not present then you can create them. **Copy only required file** , no need to copy all the files

```
/app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_Customer/templates/newcustomer.phtml
```

Make your changes and run required commands to take effect.

**In same way you can extend any module which is not present in your theme**

Never make any changes in vendor files , always extend the module

Comment: Thank you manoj i wish i could accept the both answers. cheers!

Comment: No worry bro.. Happy to help people here on forums . cheers !

Comment: some day i will return this favor by helping others when i got some command on this technology.

Comment: sure, always help other with your knowledge , this way you will learn more

Comment: i have a question what if i want to change something in the block ? then i have to put it in the block ? i mean what directory structure should be in the new custom theme folder?

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39424290/magento-2-override-rewrite-block-model-controller-helper-using-plugin-pref

Comment: but i only want to change one file i want to change the title so that what in the `Block>Form>Login.php`.

Comment: whatever you need to change , always do in your extended module

Comment: So by making a block directory in the Magento_Customer and changing it will work?

Comment: No not that way, check the answer link I given