# Proper way to get config values in overridden template in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, phtml

I need to get theme's **Default Title** configuration value in my **logo.phtml**.

So after many searches, I'm using a bad way for do that!
I'm using the **Object Manager Instance** directly in template file!

**app\design\frontend\MyVendor\myTheme\Magento_Theme\templates\html\header\logo.phtml**:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_pageConfig = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config');
$_metaTitle = strip_tags($_pageConfig->getTitle()->getDefault());
```

And it works!

**But how can I get anything from *Configuration Values* in overridden templates in proper way like *Block Class* or *Layout* stuff?!**

By the way, I'm using **Magento v2.1.9** with **PHP 7.0.24**.

Answer (score -1):

You should use Dependency Injection instead of Object Manager Instance. To do so, you should create a new module to extend the core block, then use it inside template.

1. I assume you know how to create a module. If not, refer to [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/122291/42656). The name of module is **MyVendor_MyModule** in my example.
2. After creating the basic module structure, create file `di.xml` under `app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/etc` with the following content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
       <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" type="MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Logo" />
   </config>
   ```
3. Create file `Logo.php` under `app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Block` with the following content:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Block;

   use \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo as Core_Logo;
   use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
   use \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database;
   use \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config;

   class Logo extends Core_Logo
   {

       protected $config;

       public function __construct(
           Context $context,
           Database $fileStorageHelper,
           array $data = [],
           Config $config
       ) {
           parent::__construct($context, $fileStorageHelper, $data);
           $this->config = $config;
       }

       public function getTitle(){               
           return strip_tags($this->config->getTitle()->getDefault());
       }
   }
   ```
4. [Enable the module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134093/how-to-override-blocks-in-v2-1/134106)
5. As we created a new function `getTitle()`, apply it into your template **app\design\frontend\MyVendor\myTheme\Magento_Theme\templates\html\header\logo.phtml** using the following code:

   ```
       <?php echo $block->getTitle(); ?>
   ```

More Ref.: [How to override blocks in v2.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134093/how-to-override-blocks-in-v2-1/134106)

Comment: Yes thanks. I did it earlier. but it not works! after that the **logo.phtml** not running and theme loads without this logo template! It ignored in some reason...

Comment: Did you clear cache or delete files in static folder?

Comment: Yes, I did. I deleted everything in `var and pub/static folder` and used `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `php bin/magento cache:flush`. But nothing changed!