# Magento 2 not able to override Block file

Tags: magento-2.1, override-block

I tried to override block file but I unable to see the output.

my script

**di.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Company\Cms\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
</config>
```

**Block file:**

```
<?php

namespace Company\Cms\Block\Html;

class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu{

    protected function _getHtml(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree,
        $childrenWrapClass,
        $limit,
        $colBrakes = []
    ) {
        echo "exxit"; exit;
    }
}
```

and I followed the below link for this

[How to override blocks in v2.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134093/how-to-override-blocks-in-v2-1/134106)

Comment: please let me know if you have issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to change below way for your preference,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Takeuchi\Cms\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
</config>
```

Replace **type="Company\Cms\Block\Html\Topmenu"** with **type="Takeuchi\Cms\Block\Html\Topmenu"**

Comment: i forgot to change Package & Module names in Block file. still facing same issue

Comment: try with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> encoding in your xml line

Comment: @rakesh...I tried and facing same issue and Is it mandatory create layout and template as per this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134093/how-to-override-blocks-in-v2-1/134106

Comment: you didnt create any module for above? if not without creating module its not possible to override core file

Comment: and i tried this blog also without changing names space & module names. http://catgento.com/2017/03/20/magento-2-display-category-image-in-navigation-menu/

Comment: and i tried this blog also without changing names space & module names.